# Spring Data Rest Boot app fails to start with Java config class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to run simple Spring Data Rest Boot app (v1.2.3.RELEASE) with only one small modification from working Spring reference example app (http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/) and it failed to start.

To be more specific when I use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and just following simple code configuration:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Config {
}
```

without anything else I'm getting following error on startup:

> 2015-04-20 12:07:32.250 ERROR 5693 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat ...
>
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   jug.ua.json.test.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79797226 cannot be
>   cast to
>   org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3a999d99.config()
>   ...

However following code configuration is working fine:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also if instead I use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

separate Java config class approach is working fine as well...

What I'm doing wrong, cause I can't believe I spotted such an obvious bug?

Thank you,
Oleg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be due to a name clash between the `config` bean method on `SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` (inherited from Spring Data REST's `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`) and your configuration class named `Config`. Renaming it to something other than `Config` should get things working again.

Comment: Agreed. I opened [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2852).